# is there a way to display any Well-Formed XML into a Grid or a Tree (as3)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

i have a Well-Formed XML but it change switch service, so from a data is there a way to display any XML  in a Tree or a Grid with the proviso that its a well-formed XML?
example :

```
<Document>
    <FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
        <G>
            <MsgId>msgid</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2011-03-16T15:21:42</CreDtTm>
            <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">xxxx</TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <IntrBkSttlmDt>20x3-10</IntrBkSttlmDt>
            <NbOfTxs>xxx</NbOfTxs>
            <SttlmInf>
                <SttlmMtd>INxxx2</SttlmMtd>
            </SttlmInf>
            <InstgAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BICFI>PTSxxxxxZZ2</BICFI>
                </FinInstnId>
            </InstgAgt>
            <In>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BICFI>GEBxxxx2</BICFI>
                </FinInstnId>
            </In>
        </G>

    </FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
</Document>
```

i think we should to use a recursive function !

Comment: See following webpage : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317597?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0):

if you are reusing the same node you can go for recursive function, else just find the required node and display it in grid.